# python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python

Used `python -m pip install pycryptodomex` to install pycryptodome, but the module is not found.
OS: Windows 10
Python version: 3.6.6

Comment: Just did pip install pycryptodomex and it worked

Comment: Can you provide more details into how you tried to import it? Also if you're using something like a session, can you disconnect, restart the session and try importing.

Answer (score 0):

From the [**`pycryptodomex`** package's site](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodomex/):

> All modules are installed under the `Cryptodome` package.
>
> Check the [pycryptodome](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptodome) project for the equivalent library that works under the `Crypto` package.

From the [**`pycryptodome`** package's site](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/):

> All modules are installed under the `Crypto` package.
>
> Check the [pycryptodomex](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodomex/) project for the equivalent library that works under the `Cryptodome` package.

So, don't you actually need the `pycryptodome` package instead?